# Gerrit LDAP setup and getting InitInjector failed error

Tags: ldap, gerrit, init

i am trying to configure LDAP auth setup in gerrit and  to encrypt/decrypt LDAP password from secure.config file , i used secure-config plugin. and i placed that plugin under $gerrit/path/lib and added line in gerrit.config file

[gerrit]

```
secureStoreClass = com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.secureconfig.SecureConfigStore
```

followed instruction from https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/secure-config/

then i did init like below and getting below error

```
java -jar gerrit-war-2.13.7.war init -d Gerrit/

fatal: InitInjector failed

fatal: Unable to create injector, see the following errors

fatal: 1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NullPointerException

fatal:   at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.secureconfig.PBECodec.<init>(PBECodec.java:47)

fatal:   at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.secureconfig.PBECodec.class(PBECodec.java:39) 

fatal:   while locating com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.secureconfig.PBECodec 

fatal:     for the 2nd parameter of com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.secureconfig.SecureConfigStore.<init>(SecureConfigStore.java:46) 

fatal:at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.secureconfig.SecureConfigStore.class(SecureConfigStore.java:46) 

fatal:while locating com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.secureconfig.SecureConfigStore fatal:   while locating com.google.gerrit.server.securestore.SecureStoreProvider 

fatal:   at com.google.gerrit.pgm.init.BaseInit$1.configure(BaseInit.java:274) 

fatal:   while locating com.google.gerrit.server.securestore.SecureStore 

fatal:     for the 2nd parameter of com.google.gerrit.server.config.GerritServerConfigProvider.<init>(GerritServerConfigProvider.java:40) 

fatal:   while locating com.google.gerrit.server.config.GerritServerConfigProvider 

fatal:   at com.google.gerrit.server.config.GerritServerConfigModule.configure(GerritServerConfigModule.java:78) fatal:   while locating org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Config annotated with @com.google.gerrit.server.config.GerritServerConfig() 

fatal:     for the 1st parameter of com.google.gerrit.server.config.TrackingFootersProvider.<init>(TrackingFootersProvider.java:46) 

fatal:   at com.google.gerrit.server.config.TrackingFootersProvider.class(TrackingFootersProvider.java:35) 

fatal:   while locating com.google.gerrit.server.config.TrackingFootersProvider 

fatal:   at com.google.gerrit.server.config.GerritServerConfigModule.configure(GerritServerConfigModule.java:77) 

fatal:   while locating com.google.gerrit.server.config.TrackingFooters fatal: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0):

You're following the instructions from the master branch but you're using Gerrit 2.13.7. Have you installed the secure-config plugin from master branch or from stable-2.13 one? I saw there's a difference between the master and stable-2.13 instructions in the "How to run" section:

**master**

Gerrit secure.config properties need to be generated and managed using the Gerrit init wizard. All the passwords entered at init will be stored as encrypted values and then decrypted on-the-fly when needed at runtime.

**stable-2.13**

This plugin will decode values in secure.config, it will fail if there is an existing secure.config which contains values that are not encrypted. If the values in the current secure.config are not encrypted you will need to either clear out secure.config or back it up by moving it to another file before running this plugin.

See the stable-2.13 instructions [here](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/secure-config/+/refs/heads/stable-2.13).

Comment: Hi, i am using stable-2.13 version plugin.that error resolved (changed java version to 1.8). but facing different error.    it encrypting password in secure.config file (entered password at init wizard ), but on thy fly its not able to decrypting. below is the error message

Comment: ERROR com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.secureconfig.PBECodec : decode() failed
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:936)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:847)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.PBES1Core.doFinal(PBES1Core.java:416)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.PBEWithMD5AndDESCipher.engineDoFinal(PBEWithMD5AndDESCipher.java:316)